# Why is variable declared inside IF statement created even when condition evaluates to false?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Since @A is never declared, sql server should throw an error, but it doesn’t. Why is that?

```
DECLARE @i int = 1;
IF @i > 10
BEGIN
  DECLARE @A int = 100;
END

PRINT @A; // doesn't return any result
```

thanx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SQL Server does not have block level variable scoping.

It's per batch/stored proc etc

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx) (my bold)

> The scope of a variable is the range
>   of Transact-SQL statements that can
>   reference the variable. The scope of a
>   variable lasts from the point it is
>   declared until the end of the **batch** or
>   **stored procedure** in which it is
>   declared.

Comment: Makes sense, but isn't this a flaw of sort, since perhaps there are situations where we'd like to create a variable only when certain conditions are met?

Comment: Not really. SQL is not compiled or scoped like c#, say, because it's declarative. As a developer DBA, I could say c# and Java are flawed because of their scoping rules, with variables declared in outer and inner blocks. I mean, having 2 @A vars? C'mon...

Answer (score 5):

gbn's answered the question, but on a related note, watch out for code like this :

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
WHILE @i < 2
BEGIN
    DECLARE @a VARCHAR(100)

    IF @i = 0
        SET @a = 'changed'

    PRINT COALESCE(@a, 'is null')   
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

When run, it prints "changed" twice, whereas many people would probably expect it to print "changed", then "is null". Be careful when declaring variables inside loops. You might want to explicitly set it to NULL in the declaration. e.g.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(100) = NULL
```

When this modified version is run, it displays "changed" then "is null".