# Access to not declared variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why this code give one row with `NULL` value instead of error message `Must declare the scalar variable "@i".`. And why Microsoft used this behavior in t-sql?

```
if 1 = 0
begin
    declare @i int = 1;
end;

select @i;
```

Comment: `1 = 0` ? Also, `declare @i = 1`

Comment: Double typo: `1 = 0` gets you inside the `if`, and the incorrect assignment declares `@i` but does not assign a value.

Comment: Please, try to execute this code in SSMS. It is correct. `declare` doesn't executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is variable declared inside IF statement created even when condition evaluates to false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952553/why-is-variable-declared-inside-if-statement-created-even-when-condition-evaluat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx/#code-snippet-3):

> The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that
>   can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the
>   point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in
>   which it is declared.

so in your example the scope of `@i` variable is the batch or procedure ***where they are defined.***

so the next query:-

```
if 1 = 0
begin
    declare @i int = 1
end
else
begin
    declare @i int = 3
end

select @i
```

is retrieving the next error:-

> The variable name '@i' has already been declared. Variable names must
>   be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

but your query does not.

**Update**

The Microsoft has said they won't fix this:-

[Make it possible to declare variables that are only visible within a block.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537275/make-it-possible-to-declare-variables-that-are-only-visible-within-a-block)

Comment: Geez - the answer has update section, kindly revisit.

Answer (score 3):

`DECLARE`s scope is current batch, not code block. 
So it's ok that compiler sees your variable.

The question is - why is it not assigned if it's visible. The assignment is the same as regular assigment, just written in-line in variable declaration. And assignments are commands that are affected by code flow. Here is actual execution plan for your code:

```
<Batch>
  <Statements>
    <StmtCond StatementCompId="1" StatementId="1" StatementText="&#xD;&#xA;if 1 = 0&#xD;" StatementType="COND" RetrievedFromCache="false">
      <Condition />
      <Then>
        <Statements>
          <StmtSimple StatementCompId="2" StatementId="2" StatementText="&#xA;begin&#xD;&#xA;    declare @i int = 1;&#xD;" StatementType="ASSIGN" RetrievedFromCache="false" />
        </Statements>
      </Then>
    </StmtCond>
  </Statements>
  <Statements>
    <StmtSimple StatementCompId="4" StatementId="3" StatementText="&#xA;end;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;select @i;&#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="SELECT WITHOUT QUERY" RetrievedFromCache="false" />
  </Statements>
</Batch>
```

and below is the plan for expanded declaration and assignment:

```
declare @i int 

if 1 = 0
begin
    set @i = 1;
end;

select @i;

<Batch>
  <Statements>
    <StmtCond StatementCompId="1" StatementId="1" StatementText="declare @i int &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;if 1 = 0&#xD;" StatementType="COND" RetrievedFromCache="false">
      <Condition />
      <Then>
        <Statements>
          <StmtSimple StatementCompId="2" StatementId="2" StatementText="&#xA;begin&#xD;&#xA;    set @i = 1;&#xD;" StatementType="ASSIGN" RetrievedFromCache="false" />
        </Statements>
      </Then>
    </StmtCond>
  </Statements>
  <Statements>
    <StmtSimple StatementCompId="4" StatementId="3" StatementText="&#xA;end;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;select @i;&#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="SELECT WITHOUT QUERY" RetrievedFromCache="false" />
  </Statements>
</Batch>
```