# IF statement not raising error as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, reference

Assume `@Ref <> 0` in first condition. Therefore my code will not reach the declaration of `@XYZ` *(line 2)*.

I think it must raise an error in the second `IF` because of `@XZY` was not declared.

But I'm surprised that there is no error raised.

```
IF @Ref = 0 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XYZ int

    SELECT @XYZ = RISKGROUP
    FROM POLCONT WITH (NOLOCK, NOWAIT) 
    WHERE CONT = 555
END

IF @RISKGROUP <> @XYZ  
BEGIN
    -- do something ...
END
```

For example.

In python it raises this error:

> Error: local variable 'XYZ' referenced before assignment

Comment: what is RISKGROUP ? what is POLCONT ? what is CONT ? We cannot see your screen, you have to provide us with enough information. I am guessing you need something like `select @XYZ = riskgroup from polcount ...`

Comment: And when you declare a variable, you also need to provide its type, for example `declare @xyz int`

Comment: Thank you bro, I have already edited it.

Here the variables were only examples. The main question is 'Why there is no error here' 
```
if @RISKGROUP <> @XYZ  begin
   -- do something ...
end
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952553/why-is-variable-declared-inside-if-statement-created-even-when-condition-evaluat) answer your question?

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And stop assuming a "bro" helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variable with a type before you can use it

```
declare @xyz int -- assuming the datatype of column riskgroup is also int

select @xyz = riskgroup
from   polcont
where  polcont = 555
```

**EDIT**

You altered your question since I have posted my answer, now your problem is you declare the variable in the wrong scope.

```
DECLARE @XYZ int

if @Ref = 0 
begin 
   SELECT @XYZ = RISKGROUP
   FROM   POLCONT --WITH (NOLOCK, NOWAIT) don't do nolock everywhere !
   WHERE  CONT = 555
end

if @RISKGROUP <> @XYZ  
begin
   -- do something ...
end
```

**EDIT 2**

As to your question why it does not give any error, that is strange indeed

See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df87247a6d34436dc7713060952b39de)
I would indeed expect an error, but it somehow does not

This is explained in the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187953(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as normal per design, though in my mind it is a flaw.
Also see this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952553/why-is-variable-declared-inside-if-statement-created-even-when-condition-evaluat) about the same subject

**EDIT 3**

So it seems that is does not matter much in TSQL where you declare your variables, but as a programmer I find this looking weird, so I prefer to put my variables in what is for me the correct scope.

Comment: No bro, in my example the declaration under the first IF statement.
Is it wrong idea?

Comment: Yes, always declare variables in the correct scope, make sure it is visible where needed. I always declare all variables at the top of my procedures

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot. It's very important for me.

But it is interesting that there is no warning/error from SQL in my wrong declaration statement.
Doesn't it?

Comment: I agree, I tried it and it seems to work without error, see [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df87247a6d34436dc7713060952b39de)

Comment: That is why we are Pythoners.

Comment: Although not documented as such, there are no conditional declarations: `if DatePart( second, GetDate() ) % 2 = 1 declare @Foo as Int else declare @Foo as BigInt;`.